# Is the symmetric matrix $vv^{T} - hI$ is strictly negative definite for all small enough $h>0$? Is $\det(vv^{T} - hI)<0$ for small positive $h?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n, v\ne 0$ be a column vector and $h>0.$

**QUESTION:** Is the symmetric matrix $B(h):=vv^{T} - hI$ is always strictly negative definite for all $n, v$ and for all small enough $h>0$?

**What I tried so far to check the sigh of the determinant:**

**Case $n=2:$ for sign of the determinant:**

I just checked that when $n=2,$ the matrix:

$$B(h):=vv^{T} - hI_2$$

is strictly negative definite. It's easy to check, as a simple calculation of its determinant shows that

$$\det(B(h))= -h(v_1^2 + v_2^2 - h) < 0, v=(v_1, v_2)^{T},$$

**Case $n=3:$ for the sign of the determinant**

I also did a similar calculation for $n=3, v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)^{T},$ and here we get:

$$\det(B(h))= (v_1^2-h)(-h(v_2^2 + v_3^2 - h)) + v_1^2v_2^2h + v_1v_3h^2,$$

which, upon simplification becomes:

$\det(B(h))= -hv_1^2(v_2^2 + v_3^2) + v_1^2v_2^2h + v_1^2v_2^2h + O(h^2) = -h^2v_1^2v_3^3 + O(h^2)$

which is strictly negative when $h>0$ is small enough.

**My question:** So it seems to me that $\det(B(h))$ is strictly negative definite for any dimension $n$. Is it correct? *If yes*, is there an **upper bound on $h$** that guarantees that $\det(B(h))$ is strictly negative?

Furthermore, how can we show that $B(h)$ is indeed strictly negative definite?

Comment: Take an orthogonal basis with first vector $v/\|v\|$. All vectors are eigenvectors. Can you find a condition on $h$ for which the matrix is negative definite?

Comment: Your algebra is all over the place! (Mainly because your question should have $hvv^T$ instead of $\frac{vv^T}{h}$, but elsewhere as well.)

Comment: Consider $v^T(\frac{vv^T}{h}-I)v$ as $h\to0^+$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks, edited!

Comment: It's still wrong.

Comment: @Exodd Thank you, I'll think of your hint! But is my assumption correct that $B(h)$ is strictly negative definite for all $0 < h < v^T v$?

Comment: @LearningMath, no, it's actually the opposite... My guess is that $h$ should be multiplying $vv^t$ not dividing...

Comment: @Exodd I 'm not fully sure I agree (see the edit/addition at the end to the OP), because for any eigenvalue $\lambda(\frac{vv^{T}}{h} - I)= \lambda(\frac{vv^{T}}{h}) - 1 \le \frac{v^{T}v}{h} - I< 0 \forall h > v^Tv.$ So this means all of the eigenvalues of $B(h)$ are negative, proving the claim. Is it right?

Comment: check your < and >. You wrote totally opposite formulas in the last 2 messages

Comment: @Exodd Thanks, I edited the question to make it easier

Answer (score 3):

This is false.   Take $v = (1,0)^T.$   Then $v v^T - hI$    is
$$
v v^T - hI =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1-h & 0 \\
0& -h
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which is indefinite for small $h > 0$

Comment: But it is negative definite for all *large enough* h. So, there is that.

Comment: @IgorRivin  right. Not sure what convinces students to try no examples  at all.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you - but the determinant of $B(h)=vv^{T} -hI$ will still be strictly negative, right? This is also the case for your example.

Comment: @LearningMath for two dimensions, yes. For higher dimensions, you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing, for which values of $h > 0$ does $h \, {\bf I}_n - {\bf v} {\bf v}^\top \succ {\bf O}_n$ hold?

Dividing both sides by $h > 0$ and using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we conclude that $h \, {\bf I}_n - {\bf v} {\bf v}^\top \succ {\bf O}_n$ is equivalent to

$$ \begin{bmatrix} {\bf I}_n & {\bf v} \\ {\bf v}^\top & h \end{bmatrix} \succ {\bf O}_{n+1} $$

Looking for the value of $h > 0$ at which the determinant vanishes,

$$ \det \begin{bmatrix} {\bf I}_n & {\bf v} \\ {\bf v}^\top & h \end{bmatrix} = h - {\bf v}^\top {\bf v} = h - \| {\bf v} \|_2^2 = 0$$

Hence, $h \, {\bf I}_n - {\bf v} {\bf v}^\top \succ {\bf O}_n$ holds for $\color{blue}{h > \| {\bf v} \|_2^2}$.